# Doubts about Django models primary_key and UniqueConstraint for composite primary key

Tags: django, django-models

Usually primary key means also unique (and more conditions like not null, etc.). If I have UniqueConstraint with 2 fields, including the primary key, I have 2 unique conditions (one because the primary key and another because the constraint). So that's is not the same than having a composite primary key with only one unique condition. For example, with this code:

```
class MyClass (models.Model):
    field1=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    field2=models.IntegerField()
    UniqueConstraint(fields=['field1', 'field2'], name='ConstraintName')
```

Can I insert these values (1,1) and (1,2) since the field1 value is repeated and the primary key should be unique? In that case, what's the real meaning of primary key on Django models? Doesn't it imply a unique condition?

Thanks a lot and regards.

Comment: No, you cannot insert duplicate values for the primary key field. Yes, the primary key will have a unique index/constraint.

Comment: If field one is primary key. First time it will be saved like (1, 1). The next time, it won't save (1, 2). Since 1 is already saved in field1 and it is a primary key.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So is there a way to create a real composite primary key with a unique constraint on both fields and not only in the frist one?

Comment: I guess, after your comments, that the only solution is to use a third field as primary key to not use and apply all the conditions that a real composite primary key has (unique constraint, not null, indexes, etc.) on the 2 first fields.